# Why my MutableLiveData observer isn't triggered?

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelivedata

I have a MutableLiveData of a MutableList attribute in my MainActivity whit an observer of this attribute. I'm trying to trigger the observer in a while loop by adding a new element to the list. But only when the loop finishes the observer is triggered, why?

In my MainActivity:

```
private val listOfPokemon: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Pokemon>> = MutableLiveData()

init {
    listOfPokemonGson.value = mutableListOf()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val pokemonObserver = Observer<List<Pokemon>> {
        lista ->
        Log.d("POKEMON", "+list size: ${lista.size}+")
    }
    listOfPokemon.observe(this, pokemonObserver)
    tryObservers()
}

fun tryObservers() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        var i = 0
        while (i < 50) {
            listOfPokemon.value!!.add(Pokemon())
            listOfPokemon.postValue(listOfPokemon.value)
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

the result in Log is only one row:

```
D/POKEMON: +list size: 50+
```

Comment: because `tryObservers()` runs on mainThread that the observer will run too and you are blocking your thread with the for-loop

Comment: launching the while loop in `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {}` doesn't solve

Comment: try delaying the while loop for like 300 ms between every iteration and see if the result changes.

Comment: result: D/POKEMON: `+list size: 1+` with delay(300) after `i++`

Comment: Is that the desired behavior? if yes, it means a while loop is too fast for LiveData to trigger observer on every iteration and so it's not a good test. If no, be more specific in your question please as to what is the desired outcome in the log.

Comment: if you look inside `MutableLiveData<T>::postValue` it calls : `ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().postToMainThread(mPostValueRunnable)` - and uses the same `Runnable` to post on the main thread which will just call on the mutated value, by the time this has been scheduled to run you have already called `MutableLiveData<T>::postValue` 50 times .. sometimes in may run 2/3 times .. depends... Even adding a `delay(1)` it might not work reliably.  To fix this everything has to be done synchronously.

Comment: Why you need live data for this case!. just call function/add the code where you want to invoke!